# Why do we need to separate DI wiring from Implementation in Android multi modular architecture?

Tags: android, dagger-2, square

Square Inc. has presented it's internal modular architecture at Droidcon SF'19:

https://www.droidcon.com/media-detail?video=380843878

However, I'm a bit confused with some bullets. Could you please help me?

1. Why do they actually need `:wiring` modules? I find it adding complexity:

- you get extra gradle module for each new feature
- you have to make a sort of global injection into your **Fragments** somewhere in `:app`, because **Fragments** defined in `:impl` modules cannot access it's **DaggerComponent**, which is defined in `:impl-wiring` modules. `:impl` doesn't depend on `:impl-wiring`, because the dependency is reversed.
- you cannot have an Android Dynamic Feature modules, because they should know about it's **DaggerComponent** in order to inject it's **Fragment**. But there is no way to do such injection from `:app` module, which is base-module for Dynamic Features.

so why `:wiring` modules at all?

One can merge `:impl` and `:impl-wiring`, or `:fake` and `:fake-wiring` together to eliminate all the issues mentioned above. And also, in `:demo-apps` one could just have a dependency on either `:impl` or ``` :fake``, and not on ``` :impl-wiring`(or`:fake-wiring```).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I came up with the following solution:

each feature consists of the following gradle-modules:

`api`

`impl` and `fake`

`data:api`

`data:impl1` ... `data:implN` and `data:fake`

`data:wiring`

`ui`

`demo`

So, here `api`, `impl` and `fake` as usual, but I've my data layers separated. I bought myself that I need multiple different implementation of data layers sometimes, for example - if I develop Stock-Charts App, I could rely on [Finnhub Open API](https://finnhub.io) or [MBOUM](https://mboum.com/) API or provide fake implementation.

Thus I have `data:api`, `data:implX`. Indeed, `data:api` defines **FeatureRepository** interface (one or many) and `data:implX` provides actual implementation for them. In order to bind interface and implementation, I use `data:wiring`, which defines Dagger **modules** and **component(s)**. In addition, I keep the same package names within each `data:implX` module in order to *"write-once"* the `data:wiring` module. And to replace one implementation with another, I just change a single line in *data:wiring/build.gradle* which states a sort of:

`implementation project(":data:implA")`
to
`implementation project(":data:implB")`

Also, to break the confusion mentioned in my original question, I introduce `ui` module, which contains some `Views` of a particular feature. **Fragments** go in `demo` (a standalone app to test feature) or in `ui`, they refer to `viewModel` which have some bindings ctor-injected from Dagger **component** of a feature. But the UI and library are separated here. **Fragment** instantiates a dedicated Dagger **component** that uses *component dependencies* to refer to feature's library bindings, such as *interactor* or *repository* etc.

So, to wrap up - separation between UI and business logic implementation (a "library") for each *feature* makes it possible to solve the issue. Feature's `api` declares an entry point to it's functionality as a library, and it's global access via Dagger *multibindings* from `:app`. So it can be used further in any `:demo`, `:ui` and `:dynamic-feature`.

Answer (score 0):

The creation of this type of modules is to separate even more. With this you generate an abstraction of the type of component you use (koin, dagger) and how. If the project is large, it makes sense to do it.

---

Currently I generate the following flow of dependencies between modules:

*WARNING: Check the directionalities well.*

- `:feature-A:open <- :feature-A:impl -> :feature-A:impl-wiring`
- `:feature-A:impl-wiring -> :feature-A:impl, :feature-A:open`
- `:app -> :feature-A:open, :feature-A:impl-wiring`

I'm still not sure if app should depend on `open` and `impl-wiring`, or which app should only depend on `open` and `open` from `impl-wiring`.